# Directive inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get a directive inside an ng-repeat to work.. it worked when it was hardcoded in HTML but after switching to an ng-repeat certain aspects of it stopped working.

```
<div ng-repeat="section in filterSections" filter-tray>
 Test {{section.label}}
</div>
```

I have a module with a controller that emits events:

```
controller: function($scope, $element) {
     this.activateTray = function(trayID) {
          $scope.$emit('filterTray::show', {
              tray: trayID
          });
     };
};
```

I have a directive on the page - it should receive events from the controller. Since switching to using ng-repeat receiving the event has stopped working. It still initialises, it just doesn't listen for the event.

```
.directive('filterTray', function() {
     return {
          restrict: 'A',
          require: '^filter',
          link: function($scope, $element, attrs, filterNavController) {
               console.log('this debug statement works');
               $scope.$on('filterTray::show', function(e, data) {
                   console.log('this debug statement never runs');
               });
          }    
     };
})
```

Since adding the repeat has the $scope variable been affected? Perhaps $on isn't listening to the correct thing anymore? Any ideas / tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - `ngRepeat` creates a new scope.
Not sure if events are the right design choice, but if so, use `broadcast` instead of emit, and the events will reach your directive's scope.

```
controller: function($scope, $element) {
     this.activateTray = function(trayID) {
          $scope.$broadcast('filterTray::show', {
              tray: trayID
          });
     };
};
```

- [`emit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit) shoots events up the scope tree to all ancestors
- [`broadcast`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast) reaches all descendants.

Comment: Brilliant thanks! Now that you said ngRepeat creates a new scope it makes sense. Will also look at different ways of passing the data around (as you say, events probably aren't the best way to do it). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When creating a directive that will be reused (this includes ngRepeat) it is best practice to create an isolate scope for your directive. This way you can send the `trayID` without having to use events. Check out the section on isolate scope in the AngularJS docs on directives [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).